# How can I add a fontsize selector in typo3 6.2?

Tags: font-size, typo3-6.2.x

I want to add a fontsize selector in typo3 6.2. so I have created the following three files:

```
fontsize_normal.css
fontsize_medium.css
fontsize_large.css
```

and the relevant typoscript settings looks as follows:

```
config {
  linkVars = L(0-2)
  uniqueLinkVars = 1
}

obj.fontsize = COA
obj.fontsize {
  1 = TEXT
  1.wrap = <div>|</div>
  1.value = A   
  1.value.typolink.parameter.data = page:uid
  1.value.typolink.additionalParams = &L=0

  2 < .1
  2.wrap = <div>|</div>
  2.value = A+
  2.value.typolink.additionalParams = &L=1

  3 < .1
  3.wrap = <div>|</div>
  3.value = A++
  3.value.typolink.additionalParams = &L=2
}
```

But if I include the css I am getting a blank screen, so something should be wrong

```
page = PAGE
page {
  includeCSS {
    [globalVar = GP:L = 0]
    selectorcss = fileadmin/system/Public/Css/fontsize_normal.css
    [globalVar = GP:L = 1]
    selectorcss = fileadmin/system/Public/Css/fontsize_medium.css
    [globalVar = GP:L = 2]
    selectorcss = fileadmin/system/Public/Css/fontsize_large.css
    [global]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple problems here :

'L' is used as the language variable. Using this (without disabling it) will conflict with TYPO3's languages selection. You will need to create your own variable.

Conditions can not be used INSIDE your typoscript:

```
[globalVar = GP:L = 0]
page = PAGE
page {
  includeCSS {
    selectorcss = fileadmin/system/Public/Css/fontsize_normal.css
  }
}
[global]
```

Aldo you can create a font size selector with typoscript, I think a javascript approach would be much easier and flexible.
It will give you the option to manipulate your DOM (or replacing your stylesheet, or loading a new stylesheet, or setting a new body font-size , etc ...) and you can safe your settings in a cooky for further use.

On a usability point of view, Font-size selectors are obsolete: Users can set there own font size in a browser & font-sizes should be relative (using em's instead of px)..

Comment: Ok thanks, it works now :) ... but I think some old people don't know how to change the fontsize in browser